# What can we say about open unit balls of sup-norm and integral-norm

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

> Consider the normed linear spaces $X_1=(C[0,1], ||.||_1)$ and $X_{\infty}=(C[0,1],||.||_{\infty})$ , where $C[0,1]$ denotes the vector space of all continuous real valued functions on $[0,1]$ and $$||f||_1=\int_0^1|f(t)|\,dt.$$and $$||f||_{\infty}=\sup\{|f(t)|:t\in [0,1]\}.$$Let, $U_1$ and $U_{\infty}$ be the open unit balls in $X_1$ and $X_{\infty}$ respectively. Then
>
> 1. $U_{\infty}$ is a subset of $U_1$.
> 2. $U_1$ is a subset of $U_{\infty}$
> 3. $U_{\infty}=U_1$
> 4. Neither $U_{\infty}$ is a subset of $U_1$ nor $U_1$ is a subset of $U_{\infty}$.

I really don't know from where I start to solve and conclude about open balls..Please help..

Comment: Hint: What's the relationship between a Riemann integral on the interval $[a,b]$ and the difference $(b-a)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it seems that you want to solve it yourself, I'll just give you a hint. If you want a more accurate answer, just leave a comment.

HINT: In a normed space the unit open balls is the set of all elements which have a norm strictly less than 1. Now, what does it mean that $\left\Vert f \right\Vert_1 < 1$? What does it mean that $\left\Vert f \right\Vert_{\infty} < 1$?

**Edit:** We have

$$\left\Vert f\right\Vert_1 = \int_0^1 |f(t)| ~ dt \leq \int_0^1  \left\Vert f \right\Vert_{\infty} ~ dx  = \left\Vert f \right\Vert_{\infty} \cdot \int_0^1 1 ~ dx = \left\Vert f \right\Vert_{\infty}$$

for every $f \in C[0,1]$. It follows that if $\left\Vert f \right\Vert_{\infty} < 1$, then $\left\Vert f \right\Vert_1 < 1$ also. Hence, $U_{\infty} \subseteq U_1$, i.e. 1. is true.

This already shows us that 4. is false.

Now to see that 2. and 3. (which are now equivalent) are false: Consider the function
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 2 - 8x  & , x \leq \frac{1}{4} \\ 0 &, \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}$$

Then, $f \in C[0,1], \left\Vert f \right\Vert_{\infty} = 2$ but
$$\left\Vert f \right\Vert_1 = \int_0^{1/4} 2 - 8x ~ dx = [2x - 4x^2]_{x=0}^{1/4} = \frac{1}{4} < 1$$

Hence, $f \in U_1$ but $f \notin U_{\infty}$. This shows that neither 2. nor 3. can be true.

Comment: $||f||_1<1$ and $||f||_{\infty}<1$ both..Then ?

Comment: I'm asking you to think about what each of these statements means and find a connection between them. However, if you want, I can just give you the answer.

Comment: I am unable to do..Please give more details.

Comment: I edited the answer to contain the complete solution.